# Cypress - Sorry, we could not load page

Tags: automation, automated-tests, cypress

I have problem with first visit of my page after publish.

There is test where I want to try if all pages are running so i'm trying to visit them. After publish are all pages slow and are loading quite a long time. It allways end with the same error.

[image]

In my cypress.json file is defined parameter pageLoadTimeout for 2 minutes (page is loading max 1 minute).

Do you have some ideas?

Comment: I think we need more information

Comment: I tried your page and it loads very long the first time.

Comment: What type of information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I need to always request the page and after that visit it.

Comment: How do you do that?